# Получить значение input из генерируемой формы

Tags: javascript, jquery

На сайте есть форма. Которая генерируется средства jQuery . ниже часть формы

```
<input value="" name="Vote[]" readonly="readonly" type="text">
<input value="" name="Vote[]" readonly="readonly" type="text">
<input value="" name="Vote[]" readonly="readonly" type="text">
```

В jQuery сначала создаётся форма, потом заполняется данными из БД (при помощи .val() ).
И получается что на сайте значения отображаются, но если открыть код, то там

> value=""

И как следствие я с данными значениями не могу дальше работать, при помощи jQuery.

Понимаю, что это из за того, что сначала форма создаётся, потом заполняется. 
Как в таком случае поступать? нужно после заполнения формы, с этими данными работать, а val() их не видит

Comment: Как-то вы не так элементы получаете. То, что заполненно через `val()` через `val()` можно и получить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблеме скорее всего в ваших селекторах, потому что данные заполненные через `val` также через `val` можно получить.

Пример создание формы через **jQuery** и работа с `val`.

```js
var $form = $('<form><input class="form-control"></form>').appendTo($(document.body)); //  Генерируем форму

$form.find('.form-control').val("hello"); // Записываем данные через val

console.log($form.find('.form-control').val()); // Считываем данные через val
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```